# How to change default WCF service binding?

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, svc

In my WCF I have a few services. One of them must have a bigger limit for message size so i must create another binding and change configuration.

But... i can't see any configuration of my services in Web.config - nothing. Something is default?
So where I can change service binding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In WCF 4.0+ the concept of default bindings and endpoints was introduced.  If you create a new WCF Service Application, for example, out of the box with no changes you will get a default endpoint listening at the URI of the service using `basicHttpBinding` (the default binding for `http`).

If you need larger values than the default values for binding configuration, you have two choices:

Make a default binding configuration section.  This is done by omitting the `name` attribute from the binding, like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="528880" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
<system.serviceModel>
```

Note there is no `name` attribute (the other attributes have been omitted for purposes of the illustration).   The configuration you specified is will be used as the default for any request that comes in over http and uses `basicHttpBinding`.

Create the configuration as in step 1, but use the `name` attribute and then assign that binding configuration to an explicit endpoint using the `bindingConfig` attribute, like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="528880" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MyService">
      <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyContract" />
    </service>
  </services>
<system.serviceModel>
```

The second example will assign the "MyBinding" configuration to the defined endpoint.

If you want to use something other than `basicHttpBinding` for http requests, then you can also change the protocol mapping as shown in Neel's answer.

You can also check out [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) for more information on the default bindings/endpoints/etc introduced in WCF 4.0

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change default binding to wsHttpBinding you must use:

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Comment: So i can create my own binding with my message size limits and use this protocolMapping to map all http request to use my bunding?

Comment: Changing the binding from the default of `basicHttpBinding` to `wsHttpBinding` alone won't resolve the issue.  You can define your own configurations for bindings using the existing bindings if desired.  WCF 4.0 streamlined things from a configuration perspective but also introduced a lot of confusion.

Comment: After hours of finding solutions this helped me. I hate SOAP and it's configurations.