# Change WCF maxReceivedMessageSize for HTTPS

Tags: wcf, https, web-config, wcf-binding

How can I change the web.config to define the maxReceivedMessageSize for https in my WCF webservice?

I have a WCF 4 web service operating across *HTTPS* and I want to set the *maxReceivedMessageSize* for the binding.

The web config has a protocol mapping:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

I have tried removing the mapping and using an endpoint:

```
<services>
      <service name="Company.Product.Service">
      <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://mydomain/dir" />
          </baseAddresses>
      </host>
        <endpoint address="Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="IService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
</services>
```

...

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" 
           maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
           maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
           messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

But when I remove the protocol mapping, I get:

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service
>   'MyServiceNamespace.RequestProcessorImpl' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no service element
>   matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or
>   because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

How can I change the configuration to define the maxReceivedMessageSize for https in my WCF webservice?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tim for [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500078/how-to-change-default-wcf-service-binding) which led me to an answer.

The key for me was to omit the '*name*' attribute in a binding defined as <*basicHttpsBinding*>:

```
<basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
```

This then overrides the defaul pointed to by the protocol mapping.